# Start Solr with jetty

Tags: java, c++, servlets, solr

i have a sample code java to search in my indexed data with Solr.

```
public class SimpleSolr 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException 
    {
      HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

      // http://localhost:8983/solr/spellCheckCompRH?q=epod&spellcheck=on&spellcheck.build=true
      ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
      params.set("qt", "/select");
      params.set("q", "international");
      params.set("wt", "xml");
      //params.set("spellcheck.build", "true");

      QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
      System.out.println("response = " + response);
  }
}
```

but before to execute this client application, i need to start my solr with this commande

```
java -jar start.jar
```

I need to automatize the starting of my solr server.

How can i do that?

I need to know what is the bset way to comunicate with my solr server from my C++ Application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your solr-server at boot, you might want to have a look at this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot

To communicate with your Solr sever from a C++ application, the easiest way will be to use the json api of you server by adding the `&wt=json` with your queries.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core/select?q={!dismax}&wt=json&indent=true
```

Then, you can parse the received json with the excellent JsonCPP (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

Comment: Thank you @Mathieu.. i will see that

Comment: I don't know how to deploy Solr with my setup C++ application?

Comment: You have to deploy Solr as usual (via Jetty webserver or so) and then build a cpp app which will consume the json API of your Solr server. Here's the link for the json doc: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON